# How to get SSL Cipher used when using boto3 to interact with AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, boto3, python-logging

We are using boto3 to to authenticate in AWS using STS AssumeRoleWithSAML.
I need to know the cipher suite used when establishing connection with AWS.
I added below code but it doesn't logs any info about the SSL connection:

```py
boto3.set_stream_logger('', logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
```

How can I log the SSL details here?

Comment: I couldn't find the cipher mentioned in the docs either, but this [page](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/security.html) describe how to check the protocol used.

Comment: Found the TLS Cipher details from the CloudWatch logs..